# nanoScroller showing scrollbar but not scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

The scrollbar shows up in the actual project but it doesn't work as a scroller until "Inspect Element" is clicked in Chrome.

I tried to create the same scenario in jsFiddle. (but jsFiddle is not even showing a scrollbar, because the height specified for .nano is not working)

What's wrong?

```
$(".nano").nanoScroller({
  alwaysVisible: true
});
$(".pane").css("display","block");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqN6S/2/

Answer (score 2):

I unlinked nanoscroller.css and replaced your css:

```
.nano { width: 380px; height: 100px}
.nano .content { padding: 10px; text-align: justify;}
.nano .pane   { background: #888}
.nano .slider { background: #111}
```

with a little bit modified contents of default nanoscroller.css(note different values of width and height for .nano class):

```
/** initial setup **/
.nano {
  position : relative;
  width    : 300px;
  height   : 100px;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.nano .content {
  position      : absolute;
  overflow      : scroll;
  overflow-x    : hidden;
  top           : 0;
  right         : 0;
  bottom        : 0;
  left          : 0;
}
.nano .content:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}
.nano .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.has-scrollbar .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: visible;
}
.nano > .pane {
  background : rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  position   : absolute;
  width      : 10px;
  right      : 0;
  top        : 0;
  bottom     : 0;
  visibility : hidden\9; /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
  opacity    : .01; 
  -webkit-transition    : .2s;
  -moz-transition       : .2s;
  -o-transition         : .2s;
  transition            : .2s;
  -moz-border-radius    : 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius : 5px;  
  border-radius         : 5px;
}
.nano > .pane > .slider {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position              : relative;
  margin                : 0 1px;
  -moz-border-radius    : 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius : 3px;  
  border-radius         : 3px;
}
.nano:hover > .pane, .pane.active, .pane.flashed {
  visibility : visible\9; /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
  opacity    : 0.99;
}
```

You can see result here;
http://jsfiddle.net/MxCtr/1/

So, it seems, problem was in your css.